# Python записать двумерный массив в таблицу excel с помощью openpyxl

Tags: python, excel

Совсем для чайников: как записать двумерный массив в таблицу excel с помощью openpyxl?

Comment: Приведите пример данных, которые вы хотите записать в Excel...

Answer (score 1):

Без исходных данных не совсем понятно что нужно получить. Вот несколько примеров.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook


wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

for subarray in array:
    ws.append(subarray)


array = [[10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]]

col = 8
row = 5
for subarray in array:
    for index, value in enumerate(subarray):
        ws.cell(column=col+index, row=row).value = value
    col += 1
    row += 1

wb.save('C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\sample.xlsx')
```

[image: Результат]

Все остальное можно получить либо в [официальной документации](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), либо из примеров на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/company/otus/blog/331998/).